# Share internet or files over lan cable

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

My desktop PC doesn't have wifi as it's pretty old, but my laptop has internet access through wifi.

How can I connect my desktop PC to the internet using a lan/ethernet cable? My laptop runs Ubuntu and my PC runs Windows

I tried several methods from other similar questions, but none worked. When I click on the shared connection it says

> (0) Active connection could be attached to the device.

OR it sometimes says

> (2) active connection removed before it was initialized